# Getting Null back from nodeJS when using react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

React component:

```js
import "./styles/transferPage.css";
import useFetch from "./usefetch";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const TransferPage = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { data: customer, error } = useFetch("/api/choose/" + id);
  console.log(id);

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h1>{customer.customerName}</h1>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="amount">Amount (in INR):</label>
        <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" required />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TransferPage;
```

NODE JS FILE:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const { connectToDb, getDb } = require("./database.js");
const { ObjectId } = require("mongodb");

let db;
connectToDb((err) => {
  if (!err) {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server listening on PORT ${PORT}`);
    });
    db = getDb();
  }
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("/api");
});

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  let data = [];
  db.collection("Customers")
    .find()
    .forEach((customer) => data.push(customer))
    .then(() => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.status(500).send({ error: "Could not fetch the documents" });
    });
});

app.get("/api/all/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);
  const o_id = new ObjectId(id);
  db.collection("Customers")
    .findOne({ _id: o_id })
    .then((result) => {
      res.send(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

app.get("/api/choose/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);
  const o_id = new ObjectId(id);
  db.collection("Customers")
    .findOne({ _id: o_id })
    .then((result) => {
      res.send(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

i am even unable to get the ID in console when using api/choose/:id route.
and getting null in console whenever i access localhost:3000/choose/(id)

but i get the data when i use the route api/all/:id
and get data when i go to localhost:3000/all/:id

But on the same page when i go to localhost:8000/api/choose/:id, where my server is running on, i get my full data. can anyone tell me where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import './styles/transferPage.css'
import useFetch from './usefetch';
import { useParams} from "react-router-dom";


const TransferPage = () => {


    const {id} = useParams()
    const { data: customer, error } = useFetch('/api/choose/' + id);
    console.log(id)

    return ( 
        
        <div className="card">
            <h1>{customer.customerName}</h1>
            <form>
                <label htmlFor="amount">
                    Amount (in INR):
                </label>
                <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" required />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
            </div>
    );
}
 
export default TransferPage;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).